# Error detected while processing InsertEnter Autocommands: E117: Unknown function: jedi#remove_usages

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, neovim, jedi-vim

I'm trying to setup vim-jedi on neovim.

Whenever I open a python file and switch to Insert mode I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing InsertEnter Autocommands for "<buffer=1>":
E117: Unknown function: jedi#remove_usages
```

I'm really new to (neo)vim so I'd really appreciate if could help me resolve this issue, thanks!

Below, I'm providing the information I think is relevant. Please let me know if you require me to provide anything else.

#### My setup

First I installed vim-jedi from pacman then I set my `init.vim` file to the following.

```
" My .nvimrc(init.vim) file
"

:set number relativenumber
:set termguicolors

" Plugins
call plug#begin()
    " Solarized theme
    let g:neosolarized_contrast = "normal"
    set background=dark
    Plug 'iCyMind/NeoSolarized'
    
    " Python Completions via jedi
    Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim', { 'for':  'python' }

call plug#end()

" Select Solarized as my theme.
colorscheme NeoSolarized
```

Afterwards I

1. Ran `:PlugInstall`
2. Restarted nvim
3. Ran `:PlugUpdate`
4. Restarted nvim and opened my file with `nvim db.py`.

The file I opened contains the following:

```py
"""Database management functions"""

import tasks3.tasks3.db as db


def init(db_path: str):
    engine = db.create_engine(db_path)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def purge(db_path: str):
    engine = db.create_engine(db_path)
    session = db.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def drop(db_path: str):
    pass
```

To the best of my knowledge I don't have any additional scripts for nvim.

#### Additional Note (not sure if this is related)

In the context of the above purge function if type `session.` I get the following message:

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

Comment: `jedi#remove_usages` does not exist anymore on the latest jedi-vim. So you might have an issue with your setup. jedi-vim might be loaded from two different places or something weird like that.

Comment: I'll try uninstalling the vim-jedi I installed via pacman and see if the error persists.

Comment: That actually did it! Thanks @DaveHalter.